# Why would Google Rich Snippets work for one site author but not another?

Tags: google, rich-snippets, author

I'm using the Rich Snippets with two of my websites: http://www.meow.fr and another one.

They both have the same two authors: Jordy and Jing. What is amazing is that the Google+ profile picture is shown for Jing but not for Jordy (which is me). I have NO CLUE why, it's beyond my understanding. And Jing is lucky because she didn't set a thing ;)

Please check this Google result:

https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ameow.fr#q=site%3Ameow.fr+Japan&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=vBw_T6HdBK-wiQe-7ZDhBA&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=5ee9902973786e59&biw=1205&bih=724

Check the first page, the second, the third... basically, she has a badge for all her articles, but there are none for mine.

I have no idea what to check, everything seems to be in order. There could be something wrong with my Google+ account but what? I don't know. Google is full of mysteries.

Of course I tried the Rich Snippets Tool which works perfectly for every pages.

Answer (score 4):

As with just about everything Google, setting up the information isn't necessarily a guarantee they're going to use it. If you've set up the code and the testing tools say everything's fine, that's about all you can do.

For what it's worth, I don't see author snippets for *anybody* using your link above. Also, the author snippets are still being "[piloted](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986)" and will likely come and go as they figure out what determines whether they show or not. You might try seeing if filling out the form referenced at the bottom of that page has any effect. Of course they say they probably won't be in touch about it, so for all you'd know the snippets might also just start showing on their own in the meantime.

Comment: Actually yeah, since yesterday it seems the badges are gone even from my girlfriend. It still show from time to time for one article... don't know what's happening! It's a bit random, hard to control... but yeah, it's still being piloted so I guess I shouldn't expect anything, and just do my best.