# Rich Snippets ignored by Google Search

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would Google Rich Snippets work for one site author but not another?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26240/why-would-google-rich-snippets-work-for-one-site-author-but-not-another)

I’m facing one problem here. I made Rich Snippets (with Microdata) for my website but Google ignores all of them.

Google Webmaster testing tool doesn’t detect any errors.

I’ve read that Google ignores the Microdata in hidden fields. Unfortunately this is partially the case since I use jQuery to interact with the contect, but nevertheless it is not hidden everywhere and I believe that Google should recognize at least the Microdata visible to the user permanently.

Am I missing something here? It is now about 3 weeks since I updated website with Rich Snippets.

Comment: What @w3d said, although three weeks is also not necessarily all that long.

Comment: Although the other question is specifically about author profiles, I think the answer on that question covers it, so I'm closing as a duplicate.