# Featured Snippets Not Picked By Google. Why?

Tags: seo-competition-analysis

We have added content in Tabular format in our website like Our Competitors are doing but these featured snippets are picked by Google but our Not. We are using react to develop our website? Is there any issue with our programming language our problem with our table placement.

**Some Keywords Sample & Featured Snippets Picked By Google:**
1. maldives honeymoon packages - https://www.thomascook.in/holidays/international-honeymoon-packages/maldives-honeymoon-destination
[image]

2. sri lanka tour packages - https://www.yatra.com/international-tour-packages/holidays-in-sri-lanka
   [image]
3. mauritius honeymoon packages - https://www.thomascook.in/holidays/international-honeymoon-packages/mauritius-honeymoon-destination
   [image]
4. goa tour package - https://www.makemytrip.com/holidays-india/goa-travel-packages.html
   [image]

Our URL For Same Keywords Targeting are mentioned below:

https://traveltriangle.com/honeymoon-packages/maldives
https://traveltriangle.com/tour-packages/sri-lanka
https://traveltriangle.com/honeymoon-packages/mauritius
https://traveltriangle.com/tour-packages/goa

Comment: See similar: [Why would Google Rich Snippets work for one site author but not another?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26240/why-would-google-rich-snippets-work-for-one-site-author-but-not-another)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing out adding Paragraphs, tables and Lists. You must be using the plain format, that must be the reason why google is not picking it up. Furthermore, Google reads all data in the form of Paragraphs, Lists and tables as follows;

[image]
(Picture Source: AHREFS)

Try to focus on these catagories as they get indexed more often but do not forget to use the tables;

[image]
(Picture Source: AHREFS)

he following types of search queries usually don't have answer boxes:

```
Images and videos
Local
Shopping
```

Suggestion:
If you're using wordpress, try to use a better or paid plugin, if you're already have a schema plugin, then you need to change it asap as it's demaging your website. But, also try to restructure your articles to see if they rank.

Comment: "I think you're missing out adding Paragraphs, tables and Lists." 
This is so wrong. SEs love the data that has more structure. Why else would Google be doing things like this - https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-rolls-out-new-markup-for-displaying-data-tables-in-search-results/263837/
?
Back to 1st keyword example "maldives honeymoon packages", first place in SERP is pulled from a table. 
However, there's no guarantee that your data will be featured, no matter what you do.

Comment: The answer to "why your snippets aren't showing", is somewhere else. Perhaps those other websites have more authority, trust, backlinks, some other technical things are better?

Answer (score -3):

You should provide detailed and clear information about your topic and make your content should be useful for your audience. Then Google will often give first preference to your site.

I've also found that HD pictures help.  You should add some pictures and video in your blog.  This helps Google recognize your site as a valuable content.

Comment: You should definitely be compressing your images (but not too much) to make sure your users dont have to wait 3 years for your HD images to load